# sed find replace regular expressions windows

Tags: regex

I have a latex file that contains many such expressions such as `\find{101.3}`

What I want to do is some form of preprocessing with a batch file running on windows that replaces these expressions with: `\replace{101}\and{3}`

I assume I will need to use regular expressions. Using Unix I know I can do this with `sed` and I have something that works.

`sed -e 's/\\find{\([0-9]*\)\.*\([0-9]*\)}/\\replace{\1}\\and{\2}/g' $1.tex>$1d.tex`

But how can I transfer this to the windows batch language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch. I've recently have seen some batch kungfu with string search and replacement, but I heavily doubt it is directly possible with complex regex.

Does it REALLY have to be a batch file?
Have you considered i.e.:

- installing minimal GNU environment? Then, you'll have grep, sed and others on windows!
- using PowerShell instead of batches? It allows you to write scripts that leverage full .Net class libraries, so System.Text.Regex are just at hand
- if not powershell, then using VBScript (yuck) or javascript should be possible too, but working with file i/o may get hairy..

I personally dont like powershell so I've set a PIK & Ruby 1.9.3 for such small tasks. It also imediatelly grants me a minimal GNU, so

```
pik 193
ls -al | grep foo
```

works like a charm. On windows console.

edit:

An example of string substitution in batch files: https://superuser.com/a/362405/233273 (though, NOT regex. Just constant->-constant replacement). Some answers to that question also give an example of similar thing in powershell, and there regex would be accepted too.

Comment: Thx. No it doesn't need to be a batch file. This question only addresses a part of the problem. I have a shell script that does a few things including the original find and replace. It works on my mac fine and well, but I want to also get it running on a windows machine. So I try to recode it somehow. Maybe it is possible to run it directly using one of your sugestions above? Could that be so?

Comment: If it only uses 'standard' *nix commands, then "minimal GNU environment" will provide them so you can use them inside .BAT file. However, operators like `| && ; ()` will be still different than on *nix envs. Minimal GNU may even provide you with a **bash** that will be able to run .sh scripts, so your script might be "just executable". Note that by "minimal GNU" I mean anything hat boasts that. It may be minGW package, a cygwin, or whatever-bundled-with-otherthings like PIK+Ruby+DevKit (I just remembered that Pik/Ruby does not provide it! You must have DevKit installed..).

Comment: I've just checked - pik/ruby193/devkit have bundled a mingw32 toolset. So, you can probably ignore pik/ruby and just fetch mingw, maybe it has some reasonable installer.

Comment: After installing the minGW package, I was able to run the script completely! Hence avoiding the particular problem. Many thanks for your tip.